# Why will django not recognize my url?

Tags: django, django-urls

My urls.py file in my users model is having issues. When I access localhost:5000/users/, I am given the expected page, but when I go to localhost:5000/users/1, I am given a page that states

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/1

Using the URLconf defined in ng_blog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^users/$
```

But my urls.py seems to be defined appropriately.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(
        r'^$', 
        UserList.as_view(),
        name='user_list'
    ),
    url(
        r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', 
        UserDetail.as_view(),
        name='user_detail'
    ),
)
```

The root urls.py file is

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^blog/$', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^users/$', include('users.urls')),
)
```

Comment: can you show your root url.py file ? Also you need a regex pattern in `r'^(?P<username>)/$'` Something like: `r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you root urls.py, change

```
url(r'^users/$', include('users.urls')),
```

to

```
url(r'^users/', include('users.urls')),
```

The `$` signifies the end of the url pattern. Hence the issue.

Also, change

```
 r'^(?P<username>)/$',
```

to

```
 r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$',
```

Comment: I just wanted to write this ;) +1 for you!

Comment: So the regular expression is a continuation with an included urls.py file?

Comment: From the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs  "Note that the regular expressions in this example don’t have a $ (end-of-string match character) but do include a trailing slash. Whenever Django encounters include(), it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included URLconf for further processing."

Comment: One more thing. You are requesting username, and in your example, you have `/users/1` Make sure that is what you want, or you might want to change the pattern to `r'^(?P<userid>\d+)/$'`

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that you have defined your `user_detail` view to only match URLs ending with a / character, and then not used one in your failing URL.  And (as other people have noted) your `username` pattern doesn't actually match any characters.  But from the list of patterns tried, I suspect you may have other problems in your `ng_blog.urls` file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace `(?P<username>)` with `(?P<username>[^/]+)` (or some other, appropriate pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Try r'^(?P\d+)/$' instead.

The d+ will ensure matching 1 or more numerics.